# Different IP adresses for google adsense

Tags: proxy, ip

I have 2 google adsense accounts. I plan to create one more. I want to be safe and login to every account from different IP's. I don't want to use public proxies because they can have bad history. What could be solution?

Comment: Curious as to why you feel you need to login with different IPs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access every account from diff IPs by using TOR. Check it out: https://www.torproject.org/